# Run react native 0.57.7 project on Xcode 13

Tags: react-native

How can I run my project made using react-native `0.57.7` on latest Xcode version. It keeps on giving error

```
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

The answers available on GitHub and SO asks to update project to react-native `0.62` or above.

Comment: Did you found any solution?

Comment: Instead of using the command line to run app , use Xcode.

Comment: thanks! do you have code push on your app? does it work as well? 
thank you so much

Comment: Yes @Riku I have made some changes in my app and it works well.